# Where are tag bits stored in direct mapped cache?

Tags: caching

From my understanding, direct mapped cache compares tag bits. But where are tag bits stored? Are they inside cache? If yes, are they stored inside the cache block itself and actual block size is bigger?

Answer (score 0):

The cache tag bits are the bits within an address (from the perspective of the CPU) that are used as a tag based on the size and width of the cache.

Let us assume a very simple cache with 8 64 byte lines

the 6 least significant bits represent a location within a 64 byte line. The next 3 bits would be the tag, since we only have 8 lines

bits in address:
... xxxx xxxt ttxx xxxx

Addresses 0x86 and 0x10080 would have the same tag in this example

This is an oversimplified example, and there are many nuances to caches, so I would recommend reading some more in depth material on the topic, or read about an actual implementation (i.e. a CPU manual) to get a much better feel for how this works